# Oracle multiple insert into table with FK check

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I have to insert many product value records into an Oracle table. I get all the data from an xls file, processing it with PHP and (for now) spitting out a long SQL statement. As each record is inserted, I want to check the Product IDs I got from the xls against the products already in the database, skipping the insert if the IDs don't match a product. The statement I tried is the following:

```
INSERT ALL 
INTO PRODUCTOS_X_PLANES_CATEGORIA(PXG_ID, PXG_PRODUCTO, PXG_PLAN_CATEGORIA, PXG_VALOR)
    VALUES (NULL, 123456, 81, 10000)
INTO PRODUCTOS_X_PLANES_CATEGORIA(PXG_ID, PXG_PRODUCTO, PXG_PLAN_CATEGORIA, PXG_VALOR)
    VALUES (NULL, 7890, 76, 11000)
SELECT * FROM DUAL;
```

Which gets me an

```
[Err] ORA-02291: integrity constraint (OURDB.PXG_PRODUCTO_FKEY) violated - parent key not found
```

error message. I want to check that the `PXG_PRODUCTO` key exists before attempting the insert. I should check against the `PRODUCTOS.PRO_ID` field. I tried something like

```
INSERT ALL 
INTO PRODUCTOS_X_PLANES_CATEGORIA (PXG_ID, PXG_PRODUCTO, PXG_PLAN_CATEGORIA, PXG_VALOR) 
    VALUES (NULL, 123456, 81, 10000) 
    USING PRODUCTOS ON PXG_PRODUCTO = PRO_ID
INTO PRODUCTOS_X_PLANES_CATEGORIA (PXG_ID, PXG_PRODUCTO, PXG_PLAN_CATEGORIA, PXG_VALOR) 
    VALUES (NULL, 7890, 76, 11000) 
    USING PRODUCTOS ON PXG_PRODUCTO = PRO_ID
SELECT * FROM DUAL;
```

getting only a

```
[Err] ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword
```

message. What's the correct syntax? Or, if I'm completely wrong, what should I be doing instead?

**EDIT** Using

```
INSERT ALL 
 INTO PRODUCTOS_X_PLANES_CATEGORIA (PXG_ID, PXG_PRODUCTO, PXG_PLAN_CATEGORIA, PXG_VALOR) VALUES (NULL, 123456, 81, 10000) WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM PRODUCTOS WHERE 123456 = PRO_ID)
 INTO PRODUCTOS_X_PLANES_CATEGORIA (PXG_ID, PXG_PRODUCTO, PXG_PLAN_CATEGORIA, PXG_VALOR) VALUES (NULL, 7890, 76, 11000) WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM PRODUCTOS WHERE 7890 = PRO_ID)
SELECT * FROM   DUAL;
```

still results in

```
[Err] ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `where`:

```
INSERT INTO PRODUCTOS_X_PLANES_CATEGORIA 
    (PXG_ID, PXG_PRODUCTO, PXG_PLAN_CATEGORIA, PXG_VALOR) 
    SELECT NULL, 973082, 76, 10000
    FROM dual
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM PRODUCTOS WHERE 973082 = PRO_ID)
```

Comment: I get `[Err] ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword` with this suggestion

Comment: @Adriano Varoli Piazza: Does it work if you replace `values` with `select`?  Edited in answer.

Comment: I get a `[Err] ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected` with that.

Comment: @Adriano Varoli Piazza: You're right, you need `from dual`. Added to the answer.

Comment: This isn't exactly what I wanted (a single insert statement instead of N statements) but I'm going to pick it as the answer because (a) it works and (b) given the Oracle expertise here, it would be harder to maintain a `bulk collect` solution.

Answer (score 0):

After our discussion, I now know that you are constructing the INSERT ALL dynamically, with one INTO clause per row of data to be inserted:

```
INSERT ALL 
INTO PRODUCTOS_X_PLANES_CATEGORIA(PXG_ID, PXG_PRODUCTO, PXG_PLAN_CATEGORIA, PXG_VALOR)
    VALUES (NULL, 123456, 81, 10000)
INTO PRODUCTOS_X_PLANES_CATEGORIA(PXG_ID, PXG_PRODUCTO, PXG_PLAN_CATEGORIA, PXG_VALOR)
    VALUES (NULL, 7890, 76, 11000)
...
etc.
...
SELECT * FROM DUAL;
```

You can't add an EXISTS check to the INTO clause, and so there isn't a solution to your problem using this INSERT ALL syntax.  However, constructing a huge INSERT ALL statement is not the best way to do this anyway.  I suggest you look into loading the values into arrays and using FORALL to perform a bulk insert like this:

```
FORALL i IN 1..array.count
  INSERT INTO PRODUCTOS_X_PLANES_CATEGORIA(PXG_ID, PXG_PRODUCTO, PXG_PLAN_CATEGORIA, PXG_VALOR)
  VALUES (NULL, array(i).PXG_PRODUCTO, array(i).PXG_PLAN_CATEGORIA, array(i).PXG_VALOR);
  SAVE EXCEPTIONS;
```

You'll need to understand how exceptions are handled - see [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/tuning.htm#BABIIEEI)

Comment: ahem, sorry for the example. It's a bulk insert and the PXG_PRODUCTO key might refer to different items, so it won't always be the same value.

Comment: OK, so what does your SQL really look like?

Comment: Did you?  I still only see single-row inserts of literal values.

Comment: I hadn't seen your edit. I get all these data from an xls file, and I do have literal values. I meant they wouldn't always be the same one, as I interpreted your first answer. I want to check the literal Product IDs I got in the xls against the products already in the database before I update their prices in this table.

Comment: I don't have variables, I have different literals in each row. I mean that in one row I might have a Product ID of 123465, in the next it might be 78901, in the third 123, etc. All different products, and as I think, I have to check each time, not just once at the end of the statement.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get it.  I give up!

Comment: @TonyAndrews let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2890/discussion-between-adriano-varoli-piazza-and-tony-andrews)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
INSERT INTO PRODUCTOS_X_PLANES_CATEGORIA 
(PXG_ID, PXG_PRODUCTO, PXG_PLAN_CATEGORIA, PXG_VALOR) 
SELECT NULL AS PXG_ID, PRO_ID AS PXG_PRODUCTO, 76 PXG_PLAN_CATEGORIA, 10000 PXG_VALOR FROM PRODUCTOS WHERE PRO_ID = 973082;
```

Comment: Does this work with `insert all`? I need to insert many products at once. Or is this just as efficient?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure what you are trying to do exactly. Can you show us how you are creating the original insert all statement?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a server nearby to test anything. But I don't think you can use a INSERT ALL like this. We had a situation where we had to insert a lot of records at the same time. Instead of doing multiple single insert we sent a Oracle collection to the stored procedure (several actually, depending on the number of fields to insert) and used a single insert statement to insert everything from those collections. You can then check for any business rules when you are doing a single SQL.